# JavaScript / Wicket : How to display an overlay which prevents user interaction

Tags: javascript, overlay, wicket, user-interaction

I'm looking for a solution for displaying an overlay which should prevent userinteraction. I want to start an upload and force the user to wait until it is finished. After finishing the overlay should be removed.

Background:

I'm using Apache Wicket (Java) to build my webapplication. The dialog for upload is in a ModalWindow. After submitting the Form in the ModalWindow (upload), the overlay should be shown and prevent user interaction and display some kind of a message.

Any smart ways to do that? Maybe a Wicket way or a plain javascript one?

Comment: Only client-side solutions make sense. And note that there's really nothing you can do to prevent the user from closing the browser window (among other things).

Comment: Oh, and the general solution is to have a (partially, maybe) transparent element that covers everything on the viewport. Exactly how to do that depends on the specifics of the page layout and on how many browsers/devices it needs to support.

Answer (score 0):

We use the [jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview) plugin for that. We embed it in a [IAjaxCallListener](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/attributes/IAjaxCallListener.html). In the *before* handler we block the UI and in the *complete* handler we release the blocking. However it does not work well with Wicket's modal windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that Apache Isis uses for this:
https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/839df6a389949957982543f3f715f35d81437e62/core/viewer-wicket-ui/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/wicket/ui/pages/jquery.isis.wicket.viewer.js#L88-L96
It shows a veil that covers the whole page whenever an Ajax call is triggered. The veil is not being shown only if the clicked Ajax component has CSS class "noVeil".

And the CSS for the veil is at:
https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/839df6a389949957982543f3f715f35d81437e62/core/viewer-wicket-ui/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/wicket/ui/pages/bootstrap-overrides.css#L46-L59

Comment: Isis link in no longer working. Could you paste some relevant code as well?